# Receiving email from website contact form but without content

Tags: php, html, css

I'm not a PHP dev and I tried to code my contact form in PHP and facing an issue. The contact form submits and sends me an email to my inbox but there aren't any content present. It's blank with just headers and no value from the input fields.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class="top-form">
        <div class="form-field form-name">
            <input id="name" name="name" class="input-text js-input" placeholder="Name:" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field form-email">
            <input id="email" name="email" class="input-text js-input" placeholder="Email:" type="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-form">
        <div class="form-field form-cname">
            <input id="company-name" name="cname" class="input-text js-input" placeholder="Company Name:" type="text" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-form">
        <div class="form-field form-message">
            <input id="message" name="message" class="input-text js-input" placeholder="Your Message.." type="text" required>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-field form-btn align-center">
            <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Send">
            <input class="submit-btn" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$cname = $_POST['cname'];


$email_from = 'myemail@protonmail.com';

$email_subject = "New Form Submission";

$email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
"User Company Name: $cname.\n".
"User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
"User Message: $message.\n";


$to = "info@matinint.com";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Reply To: $visitor_email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("Location: index.html");

?>
```

Comment: Your code is correct (I would check if it was submitted but in general its correct. Use F12 in your browser and look what is actually submitted when you submit the form.

Comment: It's getting submitted as I am getting the email. Just not with the input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
$email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
"User Company Name: $cname.\n".
"User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
"User Message: $message.\n";
```

with

```
$email_body = "User Name:".$name."\n User Company Name:".$cname."\n User Email:".$visitor_email."\n User Message:".$message."\n";
```

And add `headers`

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Remove `enctype="text/plain` first from form tag on contact form

Comment: Just checked. Doesn't work. It's still blank. Without input values.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and post it here

Comment: Sorry mate. Can you please elaborate? I pasted that code(print_r($_POST)) at the end of the php form. Then tried it again in my website. Please check matininternational.com

Comment: can you remove the redirection on form submit

Comment: try this. Pass headers `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";`

Comment: Adding the header just adds "Mime-version....." to the email. The email is still blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199681/discussion-between-gulshan-and-zak).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `enctype="text/plain"` from your form element.

PHP will only parse the request body and provide access to the parameters in $_POST, if the enctype is either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default, so you don’t need to specify it at all), or `multipart/form-data` (that’s for file uploads, so you don’t need that here either.)

Comment: (`multipart/form-data` makes PHP fill $_POST and/or $_FILES, based on the form field type, type=file or something else. Not relevant to your problem, just mentioning it for completeness sake.)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Sorry I had to choose the other one.